# Google Cloud Messaging (GCM) Notification receiving with logs detail

Tags: php, android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I have implement the gcm to send notification to my application and its really working perfect.

I am getting notification on device but issue is that I am getting logs detail may be in notification message instead of only human readable message that I am pushing.

[image]

Here is my code that I am using to send notification:

```
$gcmApiKey = GOOGLE_API_KEY;
$pushApi = new PushAPI();
$sender = new \PHP_GCM\Sender($gcmApiKey);
$message = new \PHP_GCM\Message("1", $messsageVal);
try {
    $multicastResult = $sender->sendMulti($message, $deviceRegistrationId, 2);
    $results = $multicastResult->getResults();
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($deviceRegistrationId); $i++) {
        $regId = $deviceRegistrationId[$i];
        $result = $results[$i];
        $messageId = $result->getMessageId();
        if ($messageId != null) {
            $canonicalRegId = $result->getCanonicalRegistrationId();
            if ($canonicalRegId != null) {
                // same device has more than on registration id: update it
            }
        } else {
            $error = $result->getErrorCodeName();
            if ($error == \PHP_GCM\Constants::$ERROR_NOT_REGISTERED) {
                $pushApi->clearDeviceByDeviceId($regId);
            }
        }
    }
} catch (\InvalidArgumentException $e) {
    // $deviceRegistrationId was null
} catch (PHP_GCM\InvalidRequestException $e) {
    // server returned HTTP code other than 200 or 503
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    // message could not be sent
}
```

Here is the link of whole API that I am using. [PHP_GCM](https://github.com/lkorth/php-gcm/tree/master/src/PHP_GCM)

I try to google it but I didn't get anything to rectify this.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: can you share server side code used to push notification?

Comment: You have to parse your response same as you parse a webservice response and show only the msg.

Comment: @YogeshNarayanan I have added my code that I am using to send notification.

Comment: @AnirudhSharma Its php API and it take the msg parameters like this: $fields = array(
        'registration_ids' => array($dstRegId),
        'delay_while_idle' => true,
        'data' => array("message" => $message)); than it convert into json and passed to curl.

Comment: I think @AnirudhSharma is correct, could you add your code for receiving the GCM message to the question?

Answer (score 0):

You have to parse your response same as you parse a webservice response and show only the msg.

Try getting the message from the received intent using:

```
String msg=intent.getExtras().getString("msg");
```

Then show the message as :

```
 NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                this).setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.app_icon)
                .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
                .setContentTitle(context.getString(R.string.app_name))
                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(msg))
                .setContentText(msg);
```

Comment: Its php API and it take the msg parameters like this: $fields = array(
        'registration_ids' => array($dstRegId),
        'delay_while_idle' => true,
        'data' => array("message" => $message)); than it convert into json and passed to curl.

Comment: @Iffi unfortunately i have no idea of php.I just showed you the code for android side.You need to apply this to your app to show proper message.